# SQL Server : remove all prefixes, split first and second name - Improve code quality

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of `Contacts` like this:

`Contact`:

```
ID  FirstName                 Lastname     Email                             Title
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Julia House                            aaaaaaa@yahoo.co.uk 
2   Mr Drew Pettifer                       drew@levales.com 
3   Nicky Thomas                           nicky@nixsphoto.co.uk 
4   Miss Al Cane                           alcane@talktalk.net
5   Mobile Communication Ltd               sales@mobilecomms.com
6   Fire and Security Ltd
```

I have around 150,000 customers that are a mixture of companies and individuals.

I'd like to split the names and strip strip out all the prefixes and stick them inside title. Any organisations, I don't mind them being a first name only or split between the 2.

Expected output:

```
ID  FirstName                 Lastname           Email                        Title
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Julia                     House              aaaaaaa@yahoo.co.uk
2   Drew                      Pettifer           drew@vales.com               Mr
3   Nicky                     Thomas             nicky@nixsphoto.co.uk
4   Al                        Cane               alcane@test.net              Miss
5   Mobile                    Communication Ltd  sales@mobilecomms.com
6   Fire                      and Security Ltd
```

Currently I have:

```
-- Update Title for all contacts with prefixes
UPDATE #TempContact 
SET Title = 
     (SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(Firstname, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName)), ' ', '') 
      FROM #TempContact TCC
      WHERE #TempContact.ContactID = TCC.ContactID 
        AND (Firstname LIKE 'Mr %' OR 
             Firstname LIKE 'Mrs %' OR  
             Firstname LIKE 'Miss %' OR  
             Firstname LIKE 'Ms %' OR
             Firstname LIKE 'Dr %')
     )

-- Remove those prefixes and split the names
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(FirstName, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName) + 1, LEN(FirstName)),
    SUBSTRING(FirstName, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName, CHARINDEX(' ', FirstName) + 1), LEN(FirstName))
FROM 
    #TempContact
WHERE 
    Firstname LIKE 'Mr %' OR  
    Firstname LIKE 'Mrs %' OR  
    Firstname LIKE 'Miss %' OR  
    Firstname LIKE 'Ms %' OR
    Firstname LIKE 'Dr %'

--After figuring this out, I intended to throw it inside the original update
```

I cannot seem to grab only the first instance after a prefix (read: second world only).

Surely there's also got to be a smarter way of writing this - I'd really like to hear your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: which one is it mysql or sql server ?

Comment: @CoderofCode sql-server

Comment: I would not modify the original values until I finish the split. This is because I would complete the split in multiple steps, not in a single query. Use a new column for "first name" (temporarily), put the values in it; when you are satisfied by the result drop the original "FirstName" column and rename the temporary one to "FirstName"; or extract the columns you need in a new table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(500)='Mr Sam'

SELECT Title,
       first_name,
       Substring(NAME, CASE
                         WHEN Charindex(' ', NAME) = 0 THEN 1
                         ELSE Charindex(' ', NAME)
                       END, Len(NAME)) last_name
FROM   (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN LEFT(@str, Charindex(' ', @str)) IN( 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Miss' ) THEN LEFT(@str, Charindex(' ', @str))
                 ELSE ''
               END AS Title,
               CASE
                 WHEN LEFT(@str, Charindex(' ', @str)) IN ( 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Miss' ) THEN LEFT(Stuff(@str, 1, Charindex(' ', @str), ''), Charindex(' ', Stuff(@str, 1, Charindex(' ', @str), '')))
                 ELSE LEFT(@str, Charindex(' ', @str))
               END AS first_name,
               CASE
                 WHEN LEFT(@str, Charindex(' ', @str)) IN ( 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Miss' ) THEN Stuff(@str, 1, Charindex(' ', @str), '')
                 ELSE @str
               END NAME) a
```

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to deal with just firstnames? E.g. John or Mr Sam. Both of these will result in lastname.

Comment: @DarkShadowAY - Updated check now

Comment: @NoDisplayName Still the same. Mr [blank-firstname] Sam. Should be Mr Sam [black-lastname]

Comment: @DarkShadowAY -  you want that to be firstname ??

Answer (score 1):

First you have to remove the salutaion From your data so you can do that in such a way:-

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET firstname = LTRIM(REPLACE(firstname, SUBSTRING(firstname, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', firstname)), ''))
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE  firstname LIKE 'Mr %' OR 
firstname LIKE 'Mrs %' OR  
firstname LIKE 'Miss %' OR  
firstname LIKE 'Ms %' OR
firstname LIKE 'Dr %';
```

Then you have to add 1 more col into your table named as lastname. And add data to that in such manner:-

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET lastname = SUBSTRING(firstname, CHARINDEX(' ', firstname), LEN(firstname)
```

this will remove your last name from first name col. then you can split your col. Such that

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET firstname = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(firstname, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', firstname)));
```

I think this might be helpful to you.